# Setting dictionary of objects as type for useState() in TS/React function components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to switch from classes to function components.

If I have a `datasets` interface already defined and would like a state variable

```
 datasets: {[fieldName: string]: Dataset};

 Example: {"a": datasetA, "b": datasetB}
```

Is this a valid way to write it?

```
const [datasets, setDatasets] = useState <{[fieldName: string]: Dataset}> ({});
```

Comment: Sure, that'll work

Comment: You didn't tried it? What is working, not working with this syntax ?

Comment: I haven't gotten to try it yet as I'm converting a few things over together. No red underline in vscode really threw me off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a valid type for `useState`

```
const [datasets, setDatasets] = useState<{[fieldName: string]: Dataset}> ({});
```

However, you can shorten it a bit using `Record`:

```
const [datasets, setDatasets] = useState<Record<string, Dataset>> ({});
```

Comment: Thank you, Looking into Records and Tuples in react now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should typecheck as is!

You can also define a type to hold the `Dataset` records, and pass that to `useState`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react';

type Dataset = {};
type DatasetRecord = {
  [fieldName: string]: Dataset;
}

export default function App() {
const [datasets, setDatasets] = useState<DatasetRecord>({});
  return (...);
}
```

[See demo here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-chatterjee-nxskd)